# jQuery tabs ui-tabs-hide failing

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

Here's a link to a [misbehaving tabs](http://www.thdyoung.com/tabtest/nested.html)

They worked then began to misbehave. If you click through the tabs you will see what's wrong.Any hints as to a solution would be a blessing.

Tom

Comment: What is it supposed to look like?

Answer (score 1):

I would put iframes inside of the tabs, which contain another set of tabs.  Nest them like that just to see how well it works.  I've done it with my own use of jQuery UI and it works well.

Comment: that's an interesting idea to use iframes  tom

Comment: @Tom some people may despise iframes, but I think theyre pretty useful for separating content and updating content. Seeing how you may have a lot of content spread through those tabs, you will only have to look for the proper html file to edit it.  Just a thought...dont hate the iframe!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an advise (like an css class) to opened tabs:
when you click on one tab, you add the class to the tab (div I guess)
when you click on a new tab, you close the selected tab and open the tab that you have clicked.

or :

by any click, you close all tabs and then open the clicked one.